# When I update database in a JTable, I get multiple Items

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable

Ok guys, I made a new update Jtable code, but it's not working, could you help me understand why?

Here's the code:

```
 private void update(){
        DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
        try{
            Connection lig;
            lig = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/bdteste","root","");
            PreparedStatement inst;
            inst = (PreparedStatement) lig.createStatement();
            ResultSet res;
            res = inst.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM pessoa");
            while(res.next()){
                int id = res.getInt("ID");
                String descriçao = res.getString("Descriçao");
                double montante = res.getDouble("Montante");
                String categoria = res.getString("Categoria_Extrato");
                model.addRow(new Object[]{id, descriçao, montante, categoria});
            }
                    res.close();
        inst.close();
        lig.close();
        }

        catch(SQLException ex){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro na base de dados!");
        }
        recdadostbl.setModel(modelo);
    }
```

And here's what happens:
[Me inserting the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iA4I.png)[Error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBIBj.png)

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 3) The IDE is irrelevant to the problem. Don't mention it in the title, or add the tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution for my problem.
When I enter my tables panels, I delete all table `model.setRowCount(0);`, and then I insert all the new and old data again with this method,

```
public void updatetbl()
{

   try {
Connection lig;
lig = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/financas","root","");
Statement inst;
inst = lig.createStatement();
ResultSet res = inst.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM extrato");
    while(res.next()){
    int id = res.getInt("ID");
    String descriçao = res.getString("Descriçao");
    double montante = res.getDouble("Montante");
    String categoria = res.getString("Categoria_Extrato");
    model.addRow(new Object[]{id, descriçao, montante, categoria});

    }

   }
   catch(SQLException ex){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Base de Dados Indisponivel"+ex );
   }
}
```